# Looping over large quantity of data in a list of list of strings crash visual studio c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm implementing a functionality for a web page that will upload large amount of data (3x10^5 rows aprox.)  to different tables in a database at the same time. The user will generate an excel file with this data and upload it to the server. I'm using C# MVC to build the webpage and "ExcelDataReader" library to read the Excel File. In the beginning, i used ".AsDataSet" method to retrieve the data but reading a DataTable was extremely slow and memory-inefficient in my scenario, so i created my own function that reads line per line and store everything in a list of list of Strings. Since i'm dealing with many tables who has a one-to-many relationships with other tables in my database i'm using dictionaries to store the entities created during the process so retrieving them will be easier if i need them later. In theory, all the operations in my for loop are O(1) so i don't understand two things:

-It takes more than five minutes to loop over half of all rows
-When it reach the half point, my visual studio just crash with no message.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and my PC stats are: i5 6500 + ram 8GB ddr4
The only program i'm running besides visual studio is Microsoft edge

The tables on my database have Indexes, so in theory querying them like i'm doing in my for loop shouldn't be slowing it down.

UPDATE
I put some stopwatches and looks like the section below the word "MATRICULA" is slowing everything down. Executing that section take 00:00:00.0018949 per iteration. Any suggestion how can i improve this?

Also, i disable Visual Studio diagnostic tools and it isn't crashing anymore, but the whole thing take like 15 minutes to complete and i would like to make it go faster.

````
var nuevosALumnos = new List<Alumno>(cantidadFilas);
var nuevosPeriodos = new List<Periodo>();
var nuevasSecciones = new List<Seccion>(cantidadFilas);
var nuevosCursos = new List<Curso>(cantidadFilas);
var nuevasLineas = new List<Linea>();
var nuevasMatriculas = new List<Matricula>(cantidadFilas);

var periodosUsados = new Dictionary<String, Periodo>();
var alumnosUsados = new Dictionary<String, Alumno>(cantidadFilas);
var seccionesUsadas = new Dictionary<Tuple<String, String, String>, Seccion>(cantidadFilas);
var cursosUsados = new Dictionary<String, Curso>(cantidadFilas);
var lineasUsadas = new Dictionary<String, Linea>();

context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

for (int i = 1; i < cantidadFilas; i++)
{
    if (dataTable[i][7]  != "")
    {
        if (!alumnosUsados.ContainsKey(dataTable[i][7] ))
        {
            llaveAuxiliar = dataTable[i][7] ;
            Alumno buscarAlumno = context.Alumno.FirstOrDefault(x => x.codigo == llaveAuxiliar);
            if (buscarAlumno == null)
            {
                buscarAlumno = new Alumno();

              ```
              gathering data
              ```
                nuevosALumnos.Add(buscarAlumno);
            }
            alumnosUsados.Add(buscarAlumno.codigo, buscarAlumno);
        }
    }
    else {
        datosErroneos.Add("En la fila: " + i + " columna: H el codigo de alumno es nulo");
    }

    if (dataTable[i][1] != "")
    {
        if (!periodosUsados.ContainsKey(dataTable[i][1] ))
        {
            llaveAuxiliar = dataTable[i][1] ;
            var buscarPeriodo = context.Periodo.FirstOrDefault(x => x.codigo_periodo == llaveAuxiliar);
            if (buscarPeriodo == null)
            {
                buscarPeriodo = new Periodo();
                buscarPeriodo.codigo_periodo = dataTable[i][1] ;
                // context.Periodo.Add(buscarPeriodo);
                nuevosPeriodos.Add(buscarPeriodo);
            }
            periodosUsados.Add(dataTable[i][1] , buscarPeriodo);
        }
    } else
    {
        datosErroneos.Add("En la fila: " + i + " columna: B el codigo del ciclo es nulo");
    }

    if (dataTable[i][6]  != ConstantHelpers.TIPO_MATRICULA_EXTRANJERO)
    {
        if (dataTable[i][26]  != "")
        {
            if (!lineasUsadas.ContainsKey(dataTable[i][26] ))
            {
                llaveAuxiliar = dataTable[i][26] ;
                var buscarLinea = context.Linea.FirstOrDefault(x => x.descripcion == llaveAuxiliar);
                if (buscarLinea == null)
                {
                    buscarLinea = new Linea();
                    buscarLinea.descripcion = llaveAuxiliar;
                    //context.Linea.Add(buscarLinea);
                    nuevasLineas.Add(buscarLinea);
                }
                lineasUsadas.Add(dataTable[i][26] , buscarLinea);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            datosErroneos.Add("En la fila: " + i + " columna: AA la descripción de la linea está vacía");
        }

        if (dataTable[i][33]  != "")
        {
            if (!cursosUsados.ContainsKey(dataTable[i][33] ))
            {
                llaveAuxiliar = dataTable[i][33] ;
                var buscarCurso = context.Curso.FirstOrDefault(x => x.codigo == llaveAuxiliar);
                if (buscarCurso == null)
                {
                    buscarCurso = new Curso();

                     ```
                    gathering data
                     ```

                    buscarCurso.Linea = lineasUsadas[dataTable[i][26] ];


                    nuevosCursos.Add(buscarCurso);
                }
                cursosUsados.Add(dataTable[i][33] , buscarCurso);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            datosErroneos.Add("En la fila: " + i + " columna: Y el codigo del curso es nulo");
        }

        if (dataTable[i][30]  != "")
        {
            //codigo, periodo, curso
            if (!seccionesUsadas.ContainsKey(new Tuple<string, string, string>(dataTable[i][30], dataTable[i][1], dataTable[i][24])))
            {
                llaveAuxiliar = dataTable[i][30] ;
                llaveAuxiliar2 = dataTable[i][1] ;
                llaveAuxiliar3 = dataTable[i][24] ;

                var querySeccion = context.Database.SqlQuery<Seccion>("select a.* from Seccion a, periodo b, curso c where a.cursoId = c.id and a.periodoId = b.PeriodoId and b.codigo_periodo = '" + llaveAuxiliar2 + "' and c.codigo = '" + llaveAuxiliar3 + "'");
                Seccion buscarSeccion;
                if (querySeccion.Count() == 0)
                {

                    buscarSeccion = new Seccion();
                    buscarSeccion.codigo = dataTable[i][30] ;
                    buscarSeccion.grupo = dataTable[i][31] ;
                    buscarSeccion.Curso = cursosUsados[dataTable[i][33] ];
                    buscarSeccion.Periodo = periodosUsados[dataTable[i][1] ];
                    if (Int32.TryParse(dataTable[i][32], out auxiliar))
                    {
                        buscarSeccion.curriculo = auxiliar;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        datosErroneos.Add("En la fila: " + i + " columna: AG no hay un número");
                    }
                    //context.Seccion.Add(buscarSeccion);
                    nuevasSecciones.Add(buscarSeccion);
                }else
                {
                    buscarSeccion = querySeccion.ElementAt(0);
                }
                seccionesUsadas.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(dataTable[i][30], dataTable[i][1], dataTable[i][24]), buscarSeccion);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            datosErroneos.Add("En la fila: " + i + " columna: AE el codigo de la sección es nula");
        }

        //MATRICULA
        if (dataTable[i][7]  != "" && dataTable[i][30]  != "")
        {
            auxiliar = alumnosUsados[dataTable[i][7] ].id;
            auxiliar2 = seccionesUsadas[new Tuple<string, string, string>(dataTable[i][30], dataTable[i][1], dataTable[i][24])].SeccionId;
            var objMatricula = context.Matricula.FirstOrDefault(x => x.alumnoId == auxiliar && x.seccionId == auxiliar2);

            if (objMatricula == null)
            {
                objMatricula = new Matricula();
                objMatricula.Seccion = seccionesUsadas[new Tuple<string, string, string>(dataTable[i][30], dataTable[i][1], dataTable[i][24])];
                objMatricula.Alumno = alumnosUsados[dataTable[i][7] ];
                objMatricula.sede = dataTable[i][13] ;
                if (Int32.TryParse(dataTable[i][35] , out auxiliar))
                {
                    objMatricula.cantidad_matriculas = auxiliar;
                }
                else
                {
                    datosErroneos.Add("En la fila: " + i + " columna: AJ no hay un número");
                }


                if (Int32.TryParse(dataTable[i][36] , out auxiliar))
                {
                    objMatricula.nota = auxiliar;
                    objMatricula.estado = ConstantHelpers.ESTADO_ESTUDIANDO;
                }
                else
                {
                    objMatricula.estado = ConstantHelpers.ESTADO_RETIRADO;
                }
                //context.Matricula.Add(objMatricula);
                nuevasMatriculas.Add(objMatricula);
            }

        }



    }

    cantidad++;

}
````

Comment: 3 millions rows from Excel into a DataSet? Hmm. Must be a better way. Can you read row by row from Excel and insert those records into your SQL Database? Avoid large DataSets at all costs.

Comment: That's what i did in the begining, but now i put it into a list of list of Strings. Basically, reading row by row and inserting in the Database is what i'm doing now in my code but i don't know why looping is going so slow.

Comment: Can you add some StopWatches and print to the console while in the loop to see what parts are slow? Definitely should be able to do 3mil rows inserting in a few minutes, and shouldn't crash. Somewhere there must be a lot of instances of something being put on the heap and causing a memory exception or something. Surprised to not see OutOfMemoryException just a crash. You could check Windows Event Logs to see if there is anything about Visual studio crashing in there.

Comment: Yes, i updated the question. It isn't crashing anymore because i disabled Visual Studio diagnostic tools but still is going very slow due to the section below "MATRICULA"

Comment: Not crashing is good news. Now you will be able to narrow down the problem by removing individual code sectors and measuring the impact. Hopefully you will find the single line that slows down the procedure.

Comment: Does the procedure slows down with every record, or the records are all processed in a constant (slow) rate?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things that have the potential to be killing performance. Looping over some 3 million rows in one hit is never going to be a good idea. Firstly you need to reserve vast amounts of memory for all of the collections and dictionaries for the processing. Then there is the fact that the DbContext is being open for the entire operation so every single entity that is loaded or associated to the context is being tracked as well. The longer a context is open & more entities that are tracked, the slower things become.

Next there are other little details that are helping kill performance. Doing a `FirstOrDefault` just to check if an entity exists is a complete performance waste. Use `.Any`.

I.e. 
if (!context.Matricula.Any(x => x.alumnoId == auxiliar && x.seccionId == auxiliar2);

`FirstOrDefault` returns the entity data or #null, `Any` executes a query that will just return True or False if the entity exists.  = Faster, and less wasted memory.

The main thing to take away from this:
Split the processing up into manageable chunks, I'd say no more than 1000 at a time. You can load your dictionary of rows, but split that up into 1000's where-by a method is called to process each 1000 in a new DbContext rather than one context across all records. If you want to be able to reliably roll back the changes if one batch of 1000 fails then I would suggest either an explicit transaction (safer, but slower) or using a marker column on the tables to indicate they are in a pending state. Where you need to track records that have been successfully imported or have issues to address, I'd recommend using lists of IDs rather than lists of entire entities to save memory.

Comment: If `FirstOrDefault` is the problem, then I don't expent `Any` to be the solution. Both are O(n) operations.

Comment: FirstOrDefault in cases where a record are found = more memory allocated for the record, plus the context begins tracking it unless otherwise detached. Both costs add up. Either way the base issue is attempting to process 3M records in memory.

Comment: The OP could try replacing FirstOrDefault with Any, and if it results to a in noticeable improvement I'll upvote your answer. :-)

Comment: hehe, it was a "little detail" not the primary point of the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using many dictionaries, and each of these requires a lot of memory. Every time a `Dictionary` exhausts its internal buffer must make a new one, and the size of the resized buffer is more than double of the previous. This happens because this size must be a prime number. Internally there is a list with precalculated prime numbers, but this list ends at a maximum of 7199369. Beyond this point the next prime is calculated by brute force. So maybe you have reached the dangerous zone where things are not efficient any more.

Source code [Dictionary.Resize](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs.html#bba8e22685381014)

Source code [HashHelpers.GetPrime](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs.html#e8668bf19da49963)

Source code [HashHelpers.primes](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs.html#19337ead89202585)

```
public static readonly int[] primes = {
    3, 7, 11, 17, 23, 29, 37, 47, 59, 71, 89, 107, 131,
    163, 197, 239, 293, 353, 431, 521, 631, 761, 919,
    1103, 1327, 1597, 1931, 2333, 2801, 3371, 4049, 4861,
    5839, 7013, 8419, 10103, 12143, 14591, 17519, 21023,
    25229, 30293, 36353, 43627, 52361, 62851, 75431, 90523,
    108631, 130363, 156437, 187751, 225307, 270371, 324449,
    389357, 467237, 560689, 672827, 807403, 968897, 1162687,
    1395263, 1674319, 2009191, 2411033, 2893249, 3471899,
    4166287, 4999559, 5999471, 7199369};
```

Comment: Is that related to the initial capacity? Because in my code i set it using the variable "cantidadFilas" which stores the file's number of rows. I think the worst case for my dictionaries is when every row has a different value, that's why i set it with "cantidadFilas".

Comment: @UrukGangsta what is the typical value of cantidadFilas?

Comment: Usually is 3x10^5

Comment: So the dictionaries have enough capacity from the start? They never need resizing? If this is the case then the problem must be something else.

Comment: I can try putting a bigger number, but in theory they shouldn't need to resize their capacity.